# I keep getting this error Error in Hive while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 2:16 mismatched input 'NOT' expecting ) near 'STRING'

Tags: mysql, sql, hive, hiveql

Error while compiling statement:

> FAILED: ParseException line 2:16 mismatched input 'NOT' expecting )
>   near 'STRING' in create table statement.

```
CREATE TABLE daily_volume (
amble STRING NOT NULL,
code STRING NOT NULL,
prod_code STRING NOT NULL,
legal entity STRING NOT NULL,
country STRING NOT NULL,
buile STRING NOT NULL,
cost_center STRING NOT NULL,
glack account STRING NOT NULL, 
inter STRING NOT NULL,
billing number STRING NOT NULL,
account number STRING NOT NULL,
transaction TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
volume INTEGER NOT NULL)

ROW FORMAT DELIMITED

FIELDS TERMINATED BY '~' 

STORED AS TEXTFILE; 

LOCATION '/user/hive/warehouse/Eav/data/dev_ans_mns.db';
```

Comment: you location should be a drive location where your file is placed and it should be in text format delimited by '~' as per your create table specification.   your location should be as  '/user/hive/warehouse/dev/data';

Comment: What do you want to achieve? What have you tried to check what is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think STRING is a valid column type in mysql and also the length of the character string is usually required

```
CHAR(30)
VARCHAR(30)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems in your script:

- NOT NULL doesn't exists in hive;
- you putted ";" before specifying the location statement!

Also, be aware that "dev_raw_mns.db" will be a folder on hdfs!

Answer (score 0):

Remove `;` from `STORED AS TEXTFILE;`

just try `STORED AS TEXTFILE`