# ParseError in CTE - Hive

Tags: hive, common-table-expression

CTE is giving parseError : **ParseException line 1:42 mismatched input 'as' expecting ) near 'cust_xref_id' in statement**

```
with table1 as 
(select 2020.cust_xref_id as 2020_cust, 2019.cust_xref_id as 2019_cust
from dea.sp_2020_us as 2020
left join dea.sp_2019_us as 2019
on 2020.cust_xref_id = 2019.cust_xref_id)
select count(distinct(*))
from tabel1
where 2019_cust is not null;
```

Can't figure out where the mistake is.
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Check This https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57273328/i-keep-getting-this-error-error-in-hive-while-compiling-statement-failed-parse

Comment: first, is `2020_cust` a valid column name in Hive? AFAIK, if the column name does not start with a string, you have to enclose the name in backticks ` (`\`2020_cust\``),

Comment: You can not alias a table with number. Change this alias`from dea.sp_2020_us as 2020` to something like yr2020. Same for 2019.

Comment: @SoumyaPandey - feel free to answer your own question. It'd be beneficial to know what worked in your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the column's name does not start with a string, you have to enclose the name with backticks (`2020_cust`).